# How to interact with d3.js mouse events from overlapping shapes?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, mouseover

I'm using d3.js to draw some green circles on an SVG container based on data in my list `myList`.

Here is an example of that circle:

[image]

Now I want to implement the following behavior:

1. When the user's mouse passes over the circle, a rectangle should appear.
2. The rectangle's top-left corner should be the center of the circle.
3. The rectangle should disappear ***if and only if*** the mouse is outside the borders of the circle ***and*** the rectangle.

Below is the code I have written to solve this problem (with @Cyril's help, Thank you!). But it doesn't work right. While the mouse pointer hovers over the circle, the rectangle is visible. However, when the mouse pointer moves South-East into the rectangle (even the part of the rectangle that overlaps a quadrant of the circle), the circle's `mouseout` event fires and the rectangle disappears -- even before the rectangle's `mouseover` event has yet to fire. Technically, I consider this to still be in the circle. But clearly d3.js does not.

So how can I implement this feature given the complexity of these mouse events and minute differences (and race conditions) that accompany them?

[image]

```
var myList = [
  {"centerX": 200, "centerY": 300, "mouseIn": {"circle":false, "rectangle":false}}, 
  {"centerX": 400, "centerY": 500, "mouseIn": {"circle":false, "rectangle":false}}, 
];

var myCircle = self.svgContainer.selectAll(".dots")
  .data(myList).enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dots")
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {return d.centerX})
  .attr("cy", function(d, i) {return d.centerY})
  .attr("r", 15)
  .attr("stroke-width", 0)
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {return "Green"})
  .style("display", "block");

myCircle.on({
    "mouseover": function(d) {
      console.log('\n\nCircle MouseOver ******************************************');
      var wasCursorIn = d.mouseIn.circle || d.mouseIn.rectangle;
      console.log('wasCursorIn = ', JSON.stringify(wasCursorIn));
      d.mouseIn.circle = true;
      console.log('d.mouseIn = ', JSON.stringify(d.mouseIn));
      var isCursorIn = d.mouseIn.circle || d.mouseIn.rectangle;
      console.log('isCursorIn = ', isCursorIn);
      if ((!wasCursorIn) && isCursorIn) {
        if (typeof d.rectangle === 'undefined' || d.rectangle === null)
          d.rectangle = self.svgContainer.append("rect")
            .attr("x", d.centerX)
            .attr("y", d.centerY)
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 50)
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("fill", "DimGray")
            .attr("stroke", "DarkKhaki")
            .on("mouseover", function(e) {
                console.log('\n\nRectangle MouseOver ***************************************');
                console.log("d = ", JSON.stringify(d));
                d.mouseIn.rectangle = true;
                console.log("d = ", JSON.stringify(d));
              }
            )
            .on("mouseout", function(e) {
                console.log('\n\nRectangle MouseOut ****************************************');
                console.log("d = ", JSON.stringify(d));
                var wasCursorOut2 = (!d.mouseIn.circle) && (!d.mouseIn.rectangle);
                console.log('wasCursorOut2 = ', wasCursorOut2);
                d.mouseIn.rectangle = false;
                console.log('d.mouseIn = ', JSON.stringify(d.mouseIn));
                var isCursorOut2 = (!d.mouseIn.circle) && (!d.mouseIn.rectangle);
                console.log('isCursorOut2 = ', isCursorOut2);
                if ((!wasCursorOut2) && isCursorOut2) {
                  d3.select(this).style("cursor", "default");
                  d.rectangle.remove();
                  d.rectangle = null;
                }
              }
            )
            .style("display", "block");
        else
          d.rectangle.style("display", "block");
      }
    },
    "mouseout": function(d) {
      console.log('\n\nCircle MouseOut *******************************************');
      var wasCursorOut = (!d.mouseIn.circle) && (!d.mouseIn.rectangle);
      console.log('wasCursorOut = ', wasCursorOut);
      d.mouseIn.circle = false;
      console.log('d.mouseIn = ', JSON.stringify(d.mouseIn));
      var isCursorOut = (!d.mouseIn.circle) && (!d.mouseIn.rectangle);
      console.log('isCursorOut = ', isCursorOut);
      if ((!wasCursorOut) && isCursorOut) {
        if (!(typeof d.rectangle === 'undefined' || d.rectangle === null))
          d.rectangle.style("display", "none");
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When SVG elements overlap, the mouse events fire for the top most element. When the mouse moves from one element to another element, the order of events is mouseout event (for element that mouse is leaving) followed by mouseover event (for element that mouse is entering). Since you only want to remove the rect element when the mouse has left both the circle and rect elements, you will need to listen to the mouseout events on both the circle and rect elements and only remove the rect element when the mouse position is outside both elements.

The following is one possible solution for determining whether or not a mouse position is inside an element. Use the svg's getScreenCTM().inverse() matrix to convert the mouse event's client coordinates to svg coordinates. Use the point to construct a 1x1 matrix. Use the svg's checkIntersection() to determine if the rectangle intersects element.

The following snippet demostrates this solution in plain javascript (i.e. without D3.js).

```js
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

var svg = document.getElementById("mySvg");
var circle = document.getElementById("myCircle");
var rect = null;        

circle.addEventListener("mouseover", circle_mouseover);
circle.addEventListener("mouseout", circle_mouseout);

function circle_mouseover(e) {
    if (!rect) {
        rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
        rect.setAttribute("x", circle.getAttribute("cx"));
        rect.setAttribute("y", circle.getAttribute("cy"));
        rect.setAttribute("width", 100);
        rect.setAttribute("height", 50);
        rect.setAttribute("style", "fill: gray;");
        rect.addEventListener("mouseout", rect_mouseout);
        svg.appendChild(rect);
    }    
}

function circle_mouseout(e) {
    console.log("circle_mouseout");
    if (rect) {
        var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
        p.x = e.clientX;
        p.y = e.clientY;
        p = p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
        var r = svg.createSVGRect();
        r.x = p.x;
        r.y = p.y;
        r.width = 1;
        r.height = 1;
        if(!svg.checkIntersection(rect, r)) {
            rect.removeEventListener("mouseout", rect_mouseout);
            svg.removeChild(rect);
            rect = null;
        }
    }
}

function rect_mouseout(e) {
    var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
    p.x = e.clientX;
    p.y = e.clientY;
    p = p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    var r = svg.createSVGRect();
    r.x = p.x;
    r.y = p.y;
    r.width = 1;
    r.height = 1;
    if(!svg.checkIntersection(circle, r)) {
        rect.removeEventListener("mouseout", rect_mouseout);
        svg.removeChild(rect);
        rect = null;
    }
}
```

```html
<svg id="mySvg" width="150" height="150">
    <circle id="myCircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="25" style="fill: green;"/>
</svg>
```

Note: I think FireFox has not yet implemented the checkIntersection() function. If you need to support FireFox then you will need a different means for checking intersection of point and element. If you are only dealing with circles and rectangles then it is easy to write your own functions for checking intersection.

Comment: Thanks @Bobby!! That worked very well. I chose to do the simple radius calculation rather than use checkIntersection() so that it works in more browsers.